# Trouble aligning conditional column in multi-index to the same index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, multi-index

I'm trying to add a conditional column that looks at the col1 and returns True if it equals 'Hello' else False. The issue is that it seems to place it at based on the alphabetical order of col1

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['A','B','Hello','C'],'col2':['foo','bar','baz','foz'], 'col3 ':['3','1','3','4']})
df.set_index(['col1', 'col2'],inplace=True) 

df['col4'] = df.index.levels[0].str.contains('Hello')
```

It's returning

```
           col3    col4
col1  col2             
A     foo      3  False
B     bar      1  False
Hello baz      3  False
C     foz      4   True
```

But I want it to return

```
           col3    col4
col1  col2             
A     foo      3  False
B     bar      1  False
Hello baz      3  True
C     foz      4  False
```

Comment: Are you looking for a full string match or partial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `eval`:

```
df['col4'] = df.eval('col1 == "Hello"')
df

           col3    col4
col1  col2             
A     foo      3  False
B     bar      1  False
Hello baz      3   True
C     foz      4  False
```

For partial string search, use `str.contains` with `engine='python'`.

```
df['col4'] = df.eval('col1.str.contains("Hello")', engine='python')
df

           col3    col4
col1  col2             
A     foo      3  False
B     bar      1  False
Hello baz      3   True
C     foz      4  False
```

---

Another option is querying `MultiIndex.get_level_values`:

```
df['col4'] = df.index.get_level_values('col1') == 'Hello'
df

           col3    col4
col1  col2             
A     foo      3  False
B     bar      1  False
Hello baz      3   True
C     foz      4  False
```

If this is a partial string search problem, use `str.contains` here:

```
df['col4'] = df.index.get_level_values('col1').str.contains('Hello')
df

           col3    col4
col1  col2             
A     foo      3  False
B     bar      1  False
Hello baz      3   True
C     foz      4  False
```

---

Lastly, if you are performing an equality comparison (and not partial string match), you can assign using `loc` and `pd.IndexSlice`:

```
df['col4'] = False
df.loc[pd.IndexSlice['Hello', :], 'col4'] = True
df

           col3    col4
col1  col2             
A     foo      3  False
B     bar      1  False
Hello baz      3   True
C     foz      4  False
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because `index.levels[0]` is already sorted, so use `reset_index`:

```
df['col4'] = df.reset_index()['col1'].str.contains('Hello').tolist()
```

And now:

```
print(df)
```

Is:

```
           col3    col4
col1  col2             
A     foo      3  False
B     bar      1  False
Hello baz      3   True
C     foz      4  False
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
df.index.levels[0].str.contains('Hello')
```

Use

```
df.index.get_level_values(0).str.contains('Hello')
```

and keep all rest the same.